# ¿Cómo extraer la fórmula de un modelo lineal generalizado mixto?

Tags: r, glmm

Estoy intentando extraer la fórmula de un modelo lineal generalizado mixto (GLMM).

El modelo lo he realizado a partir de este dataset:

```
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZqhBev5dFATvyWmCGdgU4KEi9Fsrj5lz/view?usp=sharing
```

Este dataset contiene datos de concentración (Conc: variable respuesta), maceración (Grinding : variable predictora 1) y kit (Kit: variable predictora 2).

El GLMM lo realizo a partir de este código:

```
  library(lme4)
  library(readxl)
  library(equatiomatic)

  glmer.conc.Grinding_Kit <- glmer(Conc ~ Grinding * Kit + (1|Especie),
                             family = Gamma(link = "log"),data = DATA)
```

He visto que existe un paquete llamado equatomatic que permite extraer la fórmula del modelo. He ejecutado el código de dicho paquete:

```
  equatiomatic::extract_eq(glmer.conc.Grinding_Kit)
```

Obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
   Error in UseMethod("extract_lhs", model) : 
    no applicable method for 'extract_lhs' applied to an object of class "c('glmerMod', 'merMod')"
```

¿Dónde está mi error?
Por favor, me gustaría saber como obtener la fórmula del modelo.
Si no es con esta función que sea con otra, pero lo necesito.

Muchas gracias

Comment: La librería no tiene la capacidad de extraer la ecuación de un modelo ajustado con `lme4`. Por ahora acepta objetol `lm` y algunas de las regresiones implementadas en `MASS` y `ordinal`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/equatiomatic/vignettes/intro-equatiomatic.html la referencia

Comment: ¿No existe una manera alternativa de sacar estos componentes?

Comment: La versión en desarrollo de la librería tiene soporte experimental para ese tipo de modelos. Puse una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La versión en desarrollo de `equatiomatic` tiene la capacidad de generar una ecuación para objetos de la clase `glmer`. Este es el pull: https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic/pull/167 , donde indican que el soporte es experimental, es decir, que deberías revisar que la ecuación resultante es adecuada.

Para usarlo tienes que instalar la versión en desarrollo desde el repositorio.

```
library(devtools)
install_github(repo = "datalorax/equatiomatic")
```

Y ejecutar el mismo código que tenías.

Este es el código LaTeX que obtienes:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
  
    \alpha_{j}  &\sim N \left(\mu_{\alpha_{j}}, \sigma^2_{\alpha_{j}} \right)
    \text{, for Especie j = 1,} \dots \text{,J}
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Y este el render:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sabría decirte si es una notación correcta. Veo un poco extraño que indique que alfa se distribuye como una normal cuando estás usando logGamma, pero no estoy tan familiarizado con ese tipo de modelos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @mpaladino, funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Perdona  @mpaladino al ejecutarlo me aparece un churro de ecuación que difiere de laa tuya, ¿Que es el render y como puede realizarlo al churro de ecuación obtenida?

Comment: No sé que es un churro en este contexto, pero bueno... `equatiomatic` genera el código de LaTeX y a partir de ese código puedes hacer el render para que se vea como ecuación. rmarkdown lo hace automáticamente si encierras el código de latex entre signos `$`. Si la ecuación es diferente no sabría decirte por que. Quizás no reproduje perfectamente tu ejemplo y especifiqué un modelo ligeramente distinto. Deberías validar que la ecuación y notación sean correctas, no trabajo mucho con modelos mixtos y no podría saber si está bien o mal, tienen una notación que se me hace muy rara siempre

Comment: Perfecto @mpaladino! No tenía ni idea de látex o render. Perdona por la jerga, aquí en España además de ser una comida consideramos churro para designar como algo que es difícil de entender. Muchas gracias por la explicación

Comment: No hay problema, aprendí algo nuevo. Mucha suerte con tu proyecto.